# Params missing ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

Asistencia controller gets everything from user is CRUD where user, entry, password, username exists

These are the parameters that should be updated and change the entry

```
class AsistenciaController < UsersController
  def update
    if @asistencia.update(asistencia_params)
      redirect_to asistencia_path, notice: "Asistencia guardada correctamente"
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

private
  def asistencia
    @asistencia = User.all
  end

  def asistencia_params
    params.require(:asistencia).permit(:id, :username, :entry)
  end

end
```

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: asistencia):

This is el EBR the asistencia

```
<h1>Marcar Asistencia</h1>

<%= form_with model: @asistencia, url: '/guardar_asistencia', method: :patch do |form| %> 
    <%= form.label :id, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_field :id %>
    <br>
    <%= form.label :username, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_field :username %>
    <br>
    <%= form.label :entry, "Entrada o salida:" %>
    <%= form.select :entry, [["Entrada", true], ["Salida", false]] %>
    <%= form.submit 'Registrar' %>
<%end%>
```

I tried changing the parameters, and everything remains the same, I ran out of ideas to fix it
I am relatively new to ruby ​​and need help

Hash of params:

```
Started PATCH "/guardar_asistencia" for localhost at 2023-06-30 17:02:40 -0500
Processing by AsistenciaController#update as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "id"=>"1", "username"=>"Prueba", "entry"=>"false", "commit"=>"Registrar"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:63:in `set_user'
Completed 400 Bad Request in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms | Allocations: 5996)


  
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: asistencia):
  
app/controllers/asistencia_controller.rb:16:in `asistencia_params'
app/controllers/asistencia_controller.rb:3:in `update'
Started GET "/asistencia/asistencia" for localhost at 2023-06-30 17:02:42 -0500
Processing by AsistenciaController#asistencia as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering asistencia/asistencia.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered asistencia/asistencia.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.1ms | Allocations: 3438)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 57.6ms | Allocations: 17125)
Completed 200 OK in 65ms (Views: 60.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 17673)
```

Comment: The hidden field is unnecessary and secondly your form_with is not constructed correctly. To arrange for the params to be correctly sent to the controller you should heed the response from @LesNightingill

Comment: You need to post your updated stack trace please

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Now that you have shared your entire repo, I can see a number of problems. I don't know what you're trying to do so I can't resolve them all!

1. the `asistencia` method in AsistenciaController is designated as private and it's not used. Rails is just rendering the view.
2. You initialize the @asistencia variable as User.all. This make no sense, it should be a single User instance.
3. AsistenciaController inherits from UsersController. I'm not sure why. It's unusual.
4. The definition of `asistencia_params` is incorrect. The @asistencia variable is an instance of User, so the params hash is of the form {user: {id: 1, username: 'Harry', entry: "true"}}. So the strong parameters definition in UsersController will work.

```rb
class AsistenciaController < UsersController
  def update
    @asistencia = User.find(user_params[:id])
    if @asistencia.update(user_params)
      redirect_to asistencia_path, notice: "Asistencia guardada correctamente"
    else 
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def asistencia
   @asistencia = User.new
  end

end
```

This gives an error due to the fact that there's no user id to set the user for the update action (set_user method in UsersController). I don't know how you plan to do this.

Comment: It didn't work, it keeps showing the missing parameters error

Comment: can you update your question to show the parameters hash (look in development.log) that is received by the controller

Comment: I already did it, it's updated

Comment: @William post your new form please without the hidden field and with the correctly formatted form_with as per this answer and replace your stack trace with your new stack trace please

Comment: @jamesc Okey.  let´s go

Comment: The params hash you are receiving is inconsistent with the structure of the form. Do you have another form on the page? Is the form that you have shown nested within another form? Are you totally sure that the params hash you show is produced by the form you are showing us?

Comment: @LesNightingill Of course, there is another form where the user is created but it is on another page, in another model-views
I uploaded the project to git, so they can review it:
https://github.com/Will-Belt/Registro.git

Comment: what URL do you visit to view the form that is causing your trouble? I note that the #assistencia method in AssistenciaController is private, so it is not accessible.

Comment: @LesNightingill I go to the url asistencia/asistencia
In that url is where I update the entry